# Visual Studio 2017 (or higher) configure IDE to use MetadataAsSource folder under project build folder and not in AppData\Local\Temp

Tags: assembly, reference, visual-studio-2017, metadata, rebuild

I have searched for Vs2017 (or in fact any version) configuration option to point the generation of MetadataAsSource folder under project hierarchy instead of AppData\Local\ but failed to find anything.

I have a solution. Main app is C#, but includes C++ project, which is linked to C# project as a dll assembly (**in references, not as a Nuget package**).

I can change the C++ project and re-build. All builds OK, and object explorer sees the updated C++ Wrapper class (ie. I have added a new method so I can see the new method). However if I ctrl-click on the class in the C# code it opens the C++ Wrapper from metadata (from MetadataAsSource folder) but that metadata points to the old Wrapper (new method missing).

Manually deleting MetadataAsSource folder forces the correct clean, and in both object explorer and when I ctrl-click the class I see the correct updated Wrapper from metadata.

It all builds and works as if the new changes have been applied, it is just I can not see the updated Wrapper in the metadata, so my clue is only that clean isn't cleaning the AppData folders.

Have you any configuration setting I could try?

Could that be an IntelliSense related?

I have grepped the whole project to find :
a) metadataassource (0 hits)
b) appdata (a few hits none that mentions Local though)
c) local (a lot, in cs, c++, xaml files but none being any path setting that seems relevant at all)

It is all done the GUI way, and I do not see any Makefile in the solution so I am a bit lost what clean.